# Is there a quantitative measure for a philosopher's skill?

Tags: metaphilosophy, society, bertrand-russell

> Obviously, the property you should be interested in here is *fame*.
> Below a ranking of the philosophers included in Leiter's list, sorted
> by fame (measured in dBHa, the international logarithmic unit of fame,
> see Schulman 2009).

[https://people.ucalgary.ca/~rzach/blog/2009/03/whos-most-famous-philosopher-of-20th-century.html](https://people.ucalgary.ca/%7Erzach/blog/2009/03/whos-most-famous-philosopher-of-20th-century.html)

> The top 8 are [Russell is number one] B-list celebrities, 9-31 are
> C-list, by Schulman's standard.

Leaving aside how mind boggling it is that there is a quantitative measure of "fame" or indeed why anyone would want to be a philosopher if the best they could ever genuinely hope for is a panel game show host (I'm looking at you Elizabeth Anscombe), I wondered: is there a quantitative measure for a philosopher's skill?

Comment: I cannot imagine how to define it... :-(

Comment: For meaningful comparison of "skill" the field would have to be much more narrow than "20th century philosophers". Comparing "skills" of Wittgenstein and Heidegger, for example, is beyond apples and oranges. The same applies even if "philosophers" are replaced by "mathematicians", for whom "skill" is arguably more salient. But here is ["25 Most Influential Philosophers of All Time"](https://academicinfluence.com/inflection/influence/most-influential-philosophers-study-starter) that uses influence score methodology different from Schulman's.

Comment: I agree it's difficult to compare philosophers, but there is such a thing as "skill" here in the same way that Henry viii was important and a poet @Conifold

Comment: stop voting down for spurious reason FFS this is just popularity

Comment: I know I'm unpopular, I know you don't like me or my questions, but look to yourself for a moment, for one time please...

Comment: There is a tradeoff b/w generality and cogency. We can go by importance, influence, fame and be general, but how cogent is that? Easter island statues and the Moon are important, influential and famous too. On the other hand, we could, perhaps, more cogently compare Pascal and Wittgenstein on aphoristic wit, or Spengler and Foucault on historical insight, but the skillset for philosophy at large is too multi-faceted to be reduced to a meaningful single measure. That's a big reason why single utility utilitarianism fails too. (Btw, not my downvote).